# Skimage RANSACRegressor At least 2 input points needed

Tags: python, scikit-image

`scikit-image` : 0.19.3
code to reproduce error:

```
from skimage.measure import LineModelND, ransac
import numpy as np

pts = np.array([[579,298],
 [604,276],
 [354,241],
 [156,240],
 [124,157],
 [625,105]])

model, inliers = ransac(pts, LineModelND, min_samples=4,residual_threshold=2, max_trials=1000)
```

error: `At least 2 input points needed.` at file `skimage/measure/fit.py` line 92
I haven't faced the same error with other points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The RANSAC procedure could not identify 2 or more inliers in the data.** The scikit-image implementation does not present a warning in this situation. You can either increase the `residual_threshold` or decrease the `min_samples` to "fix" this behavior.

Scikit-learn's [RANSAC implementation of RANSAC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RANSACRegressor.html) might help you out. Here, the `min_samples` and `residual_threshold` inputs are optional.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RANSACRegressor
X = pts[:,0].reshape(-1,1)
y = pts[:,1].reshape(-1,1))
reg = RANSACRegressor(random_state=None,
                      min_samples=None,
                      residual_threshold=None
                     ).fit(X,y)
```